# Iphone App crashing due to Received memory warning even if i am releasing

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, ios4, didreceivememorywarning

Every time is go to the view memory in use is increasing .. even if i am saving images. And afetr sometime the app crashed due to low memory warning. can someone tel me the solution so that the image memory is not increased.

```
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
        #import "PatientStudiesViewController.h"
        #import "CareServices.h"

        @interface newImageComparison : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate,ServerConnectionDelegate>
        {

            NSString *serverUrlStr;
            NSString *studyID;
            NSString *instID;
            NSString *urlEncodedKey;

            NSMutableArray *myCompareImage1;
            NSMutableArray *myCompareImage2;

            UIScrollView * _scrollView1;
            UIScrollView * _scrollView2;
            NSMutableArray *selectedStudyIDArr;
            NSMutableDictionary *SelectedImageTypeDict;
            NSMutableArray *selectedImagetypeTagsArr;
            BOOL isRightEyeSelectedAgain;
            BOOL isLeftEyeSelectedAgain;
            NSMutableArray *demoCompareODArr;
            NSMutableArray *demoCompareOSArr;
            CareServices *careServices;

        }

        -(void)prepareODImages_selectedStudyIDString1 :(NSString *)selectedIDString1;
        -(void)prepareOSImages_selectedStudyIDString2 :(NSString *)selectedIDString2;
        - (void)loadImageRightEyeImage:(NSMutableArray *)urlAndTagReference;
        - (void)loadImageLeftEyeImage:(NSMutableArray *)urlAndTagReference;


        @end


        #import "newImageComparison.h"
        #import "XMLParserForStudyDetails.h"
        #import "ColorSchemes.h"
        #import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
        #import "mach/mach.h"



        @implementation newImageComparison

        - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
        {
            self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
            if (self) {
                // Custom initialization
            }
            return self;
        }

        - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
        {
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        #pragma mark - View lifecycle

        - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            careServices = [CareServices currentInstance];
            careServices.delegate = self;
            NSUserDefaults *selectedStudy = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            selectedStudyIDArr = [selectedStudy valueForKey:@"selectedStudyIDArray"];
            NSUserDefaults *selectedImagetype = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            SelectedImageTypeDict = [selectedImagetype valueForKey:@"imageTypeDict"];
            NSUserDefaults *selectedImageTypeTags = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            selectedImagetypeTagsArr = [selectedImageTypeTags valueForKey:@"selectedImageTypeTags"];
            NSMutableArray *imageType = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (int count = 0; count <[selectedImagetypeTagsArr count]; count++) {

                [imageType addObject:[SelectedImageTypeDict valueForKey:[selectedImagetypeTagsArr objectAtIndex:count]]];
            }
             self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            [super viewDidLoad];
            myCompareImage1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            myCompareImage2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            NSUserDefaults *realUrl = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            serverUrlStr = [realUrl valueForKey:@"serverUrl"];
            NSString *key;
            NSUserDefaults *keyD = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            key = [keyD valueForKey:@"key"];
            urlEncodedKey = (NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)key, NULL, CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&’()*+,;="), kCFStringEncodingASCII);
            NSUserDefaults *studyID_D = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            studyID = [studyID_D valueForKey:@"studyID"];
            NSUserDefaults *instID_D = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            instID = [instID_D valueForKey:@"instID"];
            NSMutableArray *selectedDateArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"selectedDateArray"];
            demoCompareODArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            demoCompareOSArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 2, 200, 20)];
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",[selectedStudyIDArr objectAtIndex:0],[selectedDateArray objectAtIndex:0],[imageType objectAtIndex:0]];
            label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
            label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            [self.view addSubview:label];
            [label release];


            label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 208, 200, 20)];
            label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",[selectedStudyIDArr objectAtIndex:1],[selectedDateArray objectAtIndex:1],[imageType objectAtIndex:1]];
            label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            label.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
            label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            [self.view addSubview:label];
            [label release];

           NSMutableDictionary *selectedDemoImagesDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"selectedDemoImagesDict"];

            if ([[imageType objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"OD"]) {
                  [self prepareODImages_selectedStudyIDString1:[selectedStudyIDArr objectAtIndex:0]];
               }
               else {
                isLeftEyeSelectedAgain = YES;
                       [self prepareOSImages_selectedStudyIDString2:[selectedStudyIDArr objectAtIndex:0]];
             }

            if ([[imageType objectAtIndex:1]isEqualToString:@"OS"]) {
                       [self prepareOSImages_selectedStudyIDString2:[selectedStudyIDArr objectAtIndex:1]];

            }
            else {
                isRightEyeSelectedAgain = YES;
              [self prepareODImages_selectedStudyIDString1:[selectedStudyIDArr objectAtIndex:1]];
            }

            self.navigationItem.title = @"Image Comparsion";


            // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
        }



        - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
             UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(27,23,265,184)];
            imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plainbg_3.png"];
            [self.view addSubview:imageView1];
            UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(27,228,265,184)];
            imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plainbg_3.png"];
            [self.view addSubview:imageView2];

             _scrollView1 = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(33,30,252,172)];
            _scrollView1.delegate = self;
            _scrollView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            _scrollView1.pagingEnabled = YES;
            _scrollView1.scrollEnabled = YES;
            [self.view addSubview:_scrollView1];
             _scrollView2 = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(33,234,252,172)];
            _scrollView2.delegate = self;
            _scrollView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            _scrollView2.pagingEnabled = YES;
            _scrollView2.scrollEnabled = YES;
            [self.view addSubview:_scrollView2];
            int x_val = -252;
            int y_val = 0;

            float dis  = 0;
            for (int seriesCount = 0; seriesCount <[myCompareImage1 count]; seriesCount++) {
                NSMutableArray *OD = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                OD = [myCompareImage1 objectAtIndex:seriesCount];
                for (int count = 0; count <[OD count]; count++) {
                    dis = dis+252;
                    UIImageView *R_EyeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x_val+dis, y_val, 252, 172)];
                    R_EyeImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    R_EyeImageView.tag = seriesCount *100+100+count;
                    [_scrollView1 addSubview:R_EyeImageView];
                    UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
                    [activity setFrame:CGRectMake(R_EyeImageView.frame.size.width/2.3,R_EyeImageView.frame.size.height/2.2, 40, 40)];
                    activity.tag = seriesCount*100+100+count;
                    [R_EyeImageView addSubview:activity];
                    [activity startAnimating];
                    [activity release];
                    [R_EyeImageView release];

                }
                       [self loadImageRightEyeImage:OD];
                       [OD release];
            }
            _scrollView1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(dis, 0);

            dis = 0;
            for (int seriesCount = 0; seriesCount <[myCompareImage2 count]; seriesCount++) {
                NSMutableArray *OS = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                OS = [myCompareImage2 objectAtIndex:seriesCount];
                for (int count = 0; count <[OS count]; count++) {
                    dis = dis+252;
                    UIImageView *L_EyeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x_val+dis, y_val, 252, 172)];
                    L_EyeImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    L_EyeImageView.tag = seriesCount *100+100+count;
                    [_scrollView2 addSubview:L_EyeImageView];
                    UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
                    [activity setFrame:CGRectMake(L_EyeImageView.frame.size.width/2.3,L_EyeImageView.frame.size.height/2.2, 40, 40)];
                    activity.tag = seriesCount*100+100+count;
                    [L_EyeImageView addSubview:activity];
                    [activity startAnimating];


                    [activity release];
                    [L_EyeImageView release];


                }

                [self loadImageLeftEyeImage:OS];

                [OS release];
            }
            _scrollView2.contentSize = CGSizeMake(dis, 0);

            [_scrollView1 release];
            [_scrollView2 release];
            [imageView1 release];
            [imageView2 release];
        }

        - (void)prepareODImages_selectedStudyIDString1:(NSString *)selectedIDString1 {
                NSMutableArray *arr = [[XMLParserForStudyDetails sharedManager].final_ImagesDict valueForKey:selectedIDString1];
                NSMutableArray *imageIDArr = [[XMLParserForStudyDetails sharedManager].imageID_RefDict_3D valueForKey:selectedIDString1];
                NSMutableArray *seriesID = [[XMLParserForStudyDetails sharedManager].SeriesRefID_Dict valueForKey:selectedIDString1];
                for (int count = 0; count <[seriesID count]; count++) {
                    NSMutableDictionary *imageDict = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSMutableArray *imageIDArr2 = [imageIDArr objectAtIndex:count];
                    NSString *seriesID1 = [seriesID objectAtIndex:count];
                    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                    NSMutableDictionary *imageDict2 = [imageDict valueForKey:seriesID1];
                    for (int count2 = 0; count2 <[imageIDArr2 count]; count2++) {
                        NSString *str;
                        NSMutableDictionary *imageDict3 = [imageDict2 valueForKey:[imageIDArr2 objectAtIndex:count2]];
                        if ([[imageDict3 valueForKey:@"imageType"] isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
                            if ([[imageDict3 valueForKey:@"num_frames"]isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

                                if ([[imageDict3 valueForKey:@"laterality"] isEqualToString:@"R"]) {
                                    str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://%@/i2icareclientws/i2iCareAPI_Service.asmx/GetImage?key=%@&study_id=%@&series_id=%@&image_id=%@&image_level=3&format=&frame_number=&imageType=1",serverUrlStr,urlEncodedKey,selectedIDString1,seriesID1,[imageIDArr2 objectAtIndex:count2]];
                                    [arr addObject:str];
                                    [str release];

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (isRightEyeSelectedAgain == YES) {
                        [myCompareImage2 addObject:arr];
                        isRightEyeSelectedAgain = NO;

                    }
                    else {
                        [myCompareImage1 addObject:arr];
                    }
                    [arr release];
                }
        }


        - (void)prepareOSImages_selectedStudyIDString2:(NSString *)selectedIDString2 {
            NSMutableArray *arr = [[XMLParserForStudyDetails sharedManager].final_ImagesDict valueForKey:selectedIDString2];
            NSMutableArray *imageIDArr = [[XMLParserForStudyDetails sharedManager].imageID_RefDict_3D valueForKey:selectedIDString2];
            NSMutableArray *seriesID = [[XMLParserForStudyDetails sharedManager].SeriesRefID_Dict valueForKey:selectedIDString2];
            for (int count = 0; count <[seriesID count]; count++) {
                NSMutableDictionary *imageDict = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
                NSMutableArray *imageIDArr2 = [imageIDArr objectAtIndex:count];
                NSString *seriesID1 = [seriesID objectAtIndex:count];
                NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                NSMutableDictionary *imageDict2 = [imageDict valueForKey:seriesID1];
                for (int count2 = 0; count2 <[imageIDArr2 count]; count2++) {
                    NSString *str;

                    NSMutableDictionary *imageDict3 = [imageDict2 valueForKey:[imageIDArr2 objectAtIndex:count2]];

                    if ([[imageDict3 valueForKey:@"imageType"] isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
                        if ([[imageDict3 valueForKey:@"num_frames"]isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

                            if ([[imageDict3 valueForKey:@"laterality"] isEqualToString:@"L"]) {

                                str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"http://%@/i2icareclientws/i2iCareAPI_Service.asmx/GetImage?key=%@&study_id=%@&series_id=%@&image_id=%@&image_level=3&format=&frame_number=&imageType=1",serverUrlStr,urlEncodedKey,selectedIDString2,seriesID1,[imageIDArr2 objectAtIndex:count2]];
                                [arr addObject:str];
                                [str release];

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                            if (isLeftEyeSelectedAgain == YES) {
                                [myCompareImage1 addObject:arr];
                                isLeftEyeSelectedAgain = NO;
                            }
                            else {
                                [myCompareImage2 addObject:arr];
                             }



                [arr release];
            }

        }


        - (void)loadImageRightEyeImage:(NSMutableArray *)urlAndTagReference {
                for (int count = 0; count  <[myCompareImage1 count]; count ++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < [urlAndTagReference count]; i++) {

                    NSString *imagePath = [urlAndTagReference objectAtIndex:i];
                    imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"amp;" withString:@""];
                    imagePath = [imagePath stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
                    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSString *key = [self sha1:imagePath];
                    NSString *fileToSave = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",key]];


                    for ( UIImageView *imgView in _scrollView1.subviews) {
                        if (imgView.tag == count *100+100+i) {
                            for (UIActivityIndicatorView *activity in [imgView subviews]) {
                                if ([activity isKindOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]]) {
                                    if (activity.tag == count *100+100+i) {
                                        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileToSave];
                                        if (!fileExists)
                                        {
                                            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW,  0ul);

                                            dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                                                NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagePath]];


                                                UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

                                                NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.001);

                                                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileToSave contents:jpegData attributes:nil];

                                                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                    imgView.image = image;
                                                    [activity stopAnimating]; 
                                                    [activity removeFromSuperview];
                                                });
                                            });

                                        }else{
                                            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileToSave];
                                            if(!image) image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rest-blank-thumbnail.png"];
                                            imgView.image = image;
                                            [activity removeFromSuperview];

                                        }

                                    }


                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        - (void)loadImageLeftEyeImage:(NSMutableArray *)urlAndTagReference {
            for (int count = 0; count  <[myCompareImage2 count]; count ++) {

                for (int i = 0; i < [urlAndTagReference count]; i++) {

                    NSString *imagePath = [urlAndTagReference objectAtIndex:i];
                    imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"amp;" withString:@""];
                    imagePath = [imagePath stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
                    NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSString *key = [self sha1:imagePath];
                    NSString *fileToSave = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",key]];


                    for ( UIImageView *imgView in _scrollView2.subviews) {
                        if (imgView.tag == count *100+100+i) {
                            for (UIActivityIndicatorView *activity in [imgView subviews]) {
                                if ([activity isKindOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]]) {
                                    if (activity.tag == count *100+100+i) {
                                        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileToSave];
                                        if (!fileExists)
                                        {
                                            dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW,  0ul);
                                            dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                                                NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagePath]];


                                                UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

                                                NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.001);

                                                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileToSave contents:jpegData attributes:nil];
                                                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                    imgView.image = image;
                                                    [activity stopAnimating]; 
                                                    [activity removeFromSuperview];
                                                });
                                            });

                                        }else{
                                            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileToSave];
                                            if(!image) image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rest-blank-thumbnail.png"];

                                            imgView.image = image;
                                            [activity removeFromSuperview];

                                        }

                                    }


                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                       }
                   }
        }



        -(NSString*) sha1: (NSString *)str
        {
            const char *cstr = [str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:str.length];

            uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

            CC_SHA1(data.bytes, data.length, digest);

            NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

            for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
                [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
            return output;
        }



        - (void)viewDidUnload {

            _scrollView1 = nil;
            _scrollView2 = nil;

        }
        - (void)dealloc {
           [myCompareImage1 release];
            [myCompareImage2 release];

        }
```

Comment: Use ARC... It will remove the memory issues :)

Comment: The first thing I see is that you are adding new subviews EVERY TIME your view becomes visible. But I'm not sure if the problem is this, there is a lot of code but no precise explanation of what is happening and when.

Comment: yes i am creating the view everytime but i am also releasing the views . And i am downloading images for the first time and saving the images in NSDocument Directory but next time i am not downloading the images instead i am getting it from the NSDocument Directory but still the memory is getting increased.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Zombies turned on (scheme diagnostics) then nothing is ever actually deleted. So on devices with less RAM (Like iPad 1) you will quickly run out of memory and get a memory warning. THe simulator doesn't have this issue usually.

Comment: I have even checked that. Zombies are turned off still its still the app is crashing after getting the memory warning. And I have tried almost everything but I m not able to get any success.. dont know what to do with it ...m stuck .. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can find memory leaks using Profiler in XCode - Product | Profile in Main menu.
Then choose Memory -> Leaks.

Also, you can find some interesting suggestions using Product | Analyze in XCode.

Comment: I cant use the ARC cause the App is larger and then i will have to remove release everywhere..

Comment: You don't need ARC, this tool available in all cases.